# Include distribution folder of frontend build in the JAR with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am a gradle beginner and I am struggling to include the frontend distribution build folder in the backend jar (I use Spring Boot and the frontend is an ionic app). In the backend.gradle, I configured the jar-Task that should include the frontend-build folder (called www) into build folder of the backend. The jar task runs through, but the desired artifacts are not present in the backend-build folder and therefore not in the final jar. Would be glad for any help.

project structure:

```
project
build.gradle
settings.gradle
backend
--> backend.gradle
frontend
--> frontend.gradle
```

settings.gradle

```
include 'backend'
include 'frontend'

rootProject.children.each {
    it.buildFileName = it.name + '.gradle'
}
```

build.gradle

```
allprojects {

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'idea'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }    
}
```

frontend.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}   

task clean(dependsOn: 'npm_run_clean') {
}

task build(dependsOn: 'npm_run_build') {
}
```

backend.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'ch.renewinkler'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8


jar {
    from('frontend/www') {
        into('public')
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn(':frontend:build')

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell gradle that the jar task depends on the frontend's build task, otherwise it could run the jar file before the build task, and thus have nothing to include in the jar.

It's also a better idea to refer to projects by their name, instead of using absolute paths:

```
jar {
    dependsOn(':frontend:build')

    into('public') {
        from "${project(':frontend').projectDir}/www"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help